# when going nearly the speed of sound how fast does sound seem to go?

Tags: doppler, speed-of-sound

if one were to calculate the speed of incoming sound as one travels closer to the speed of sound what is the speed of the incoming sound for the observer?

Comment: Perhaps this has already been answered: http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/what-would-sound-sound-like-at-the-speed-of-sound?rq=1

Comment: @MarkDurham those are some amazing answers! Thanks for the link!